# How to export a function in nodejs that I made

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Every time I try to import into my nodejs file I get the error, cannot import outside a module

I have tried multiple solutions on StackOverFlow such as adding

"type":"module"

and setting file extensions to .mjs

I want to import constants from a different file but I am not sure how to

example

functions.js

```
export const myFunc = (param1) => return 'hello'
```

backend.js

```
import {myFun} from './.js'
```

How should I import them?

Sorry I accessed a similar question for constants but the same method does not work for functions

Comment: `backend.js` should be `import {myFun} from './functions.js'`

Comment: As soon as I type import it throws an error that says unexpected token 'export'

Comment: Try to change the file name from `functions.js` to `functions.mjs`. Update the import to `import {myFun} from './functions.mjs'`

Answer (score 0):

First, `"type": "module"` needs to be in the `package.json` or both JS files need to end in `.mjs`. You seem to be aware of this, but just making sure as the filenames you have provided don't end in `.mjs`, and you haven't provided your `package.json`.

When using arrow functions, the return is implied. If you try to use `return` in an arrow function, an error will occur. Also, in `backend.js`, you are importing `myFun`, which is not in `functions.js`. I believe you meant to import `myFunc`.

`functions.mjs`

```js
export const myFunc = (param1) => "hello"
```

`backend.mjs`

```js
import { myFunc } from './functions.mjs'

console.log(myFunc("test"))
```